# mostrar y ocultar contenido con checkbox PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo este codigo en PHP lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de selecionar el checkbox me muestre la tabla y cuando no este seleccionado el checkbox la tabla se oculte

```
if ( $e_mail == "e_mail" ) {
    echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"checkbox\" NAME=\"e_mail\" VALUE=\"e_mail\" CHECKED>";
    $v_s[6] = 1;
} else {
    echo "<INPUT TYPE=\"checkbox\" NAME=\"e_mail\" VALUE=\"e_mail\">";
    $v_s[6] = 0;
}


if ( $v_s[6] == 0 ) {
    echo "<th>Email Address</th>";
}


    $client_id = 1;
    $cur_line = "<tr>";
    if ( $v_s[6] == 0 ) {
    $e_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT email_assress FROM c_email 
                WHERE owner_id = $client_id AND owner_type = 'CL'";

    $e_result = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $e_sql) or 

            die ("Couldn't get email address.<br>-$sql-");

    if ( $e_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($e_result) ) {

        $em_addr = $e_row['email_assress'];

        $em_addr = trim($em_addr);

        if ( $em_addr == "" ) {     

            $em_addr = "&nbsp;";

        }

    } else {
        $em_addr = "&nbsp;";

    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($e_result);
    $cur_line .= "<td>$em_addr</td>";

    $cur_line .= "</tr>";
        if ( $only_selected == "only_selected" ) {
            if ( $ods > 0 || $sn_line != "" ) {
                echo "$cur_line";
            }
        } else {
            echo "$cur_line";
        }
}
```

En la imagen muestra el resultado pero no funciona el checkbox, alguna sugerencia que me puedan dar?, o porque no funciona mi checkbox?, por favor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías utilizar jQuery, las acciones se realizan sin recargar la página.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas utilizar un evento que 'escuche' la accion *onclick* de tu checkbox. Asi cuando detecte la acción desencadenará el conjunto de acciones definidas en tu función. Por ejemplo:

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```

Javacript:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Nota como se establece una funcion sobre el atributo`onclick`, el mismo que representa un evento del elemento. Esta es solo una manera de hacerlo. El mecanismo que uses depende de las necesidades de tu proyecto. Suerte.